# Python Logger is not working to write to file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create logger file inside directory using the below code -

```
def createLogger(name,log_path=None):
  
    logger = logging.getLogger(name) 
    
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    logger.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
    
    formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(levelname)-8s - %(message)s")

    stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    logger.addHandler(stream_handler)
    if log_path is not None:
        
        file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_path)
        file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(file_handler)
        
    return logger
```

```
name = "temp_logs"

file = open(os.path.join(f'{current_date}', f'{name}_{current_timestamp}.txt'), 'w')

log_path  = f"{current_date}/{name}_{current_timestamp}.txt"

logger = createLogger(name = name ,log_path = log_path)

write_message = logger.debug('This is a test file')

file.writelines(str(write_message))

file.close()
```

However, it is just writing `None` as message inside the file.
Am I missing anything here? Please help.

Comment: You are aware that only the last level set counts?

Comment: @KlausD. - Yes I'm aware about it. I have tried removing the others as well (and keeping just the Debug level). Still the same!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several issues. `setLevel` sets a threshold. When called multiple times, the last one wins (i.e. `CRITICAL`). You will not see any debug messages, warnings or error.

Also, you are writing to the log file directly. What's the point of setting a logger with a formatter and then bypassing it?

Try this:

Leave only this one `setLevel` call: `logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)` in `createLogger()` and then:

```
name = "temp_logs"
logger = createLogger(name = name ,log_path = './test.log')
logger.debug('This is a debug message')
logger.error('This is an error')
```

Comment: Can i use file name as earlier here ? Actually, need to create the file in that format itself.

Comment: @DexCode Sure, adjust as needed. This is just a simple example of logger usage. One note though, absolute filenames should be preferred.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot for the quick turnaround. Really appreciated!